# JS - How to turn Image object into grayscale and display it

Tags: javascript, image, data-url

Basically, when a button is clicked, it'll tell the mobile device to go to the camera. Once the camera takes a picture, it'll give me the image data (is it called the data URL?). This is my code to handle it:

```
var imagesrc = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;

var myimage = new Image(500, 500);
myimage.src = imagesrc;            <---- to populate the object with the colored image
myimage.src = grayscale(myimage);  <---- here I set it to the grayscale image
```

I want to call a method called `grayscale()` and make it return the image that's been turned into grayscale. I tried this:

```
function grayscale(image){
    var canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var imgW = image.width;
    var imgH = image.height;
    canvas.width = imgW;
    canvas.height = imgH;

    canvasContext.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

    var imgPixels = canvasContext.getImageData(0, 0, imgW, imgH);


    for(>var y = 0; y < imgPixels.height; y++){
        for(>var x = 0; x < imgPixels.width; x++){
          var i = (y * 4) * imgPixels.width + x * 4;
          var avg = (imgPixels.data[i] + imgPixels.data[i + 1] + imgPixels.data[i + 2]) / 3;
          imgPixels.data[i] = avg;
          imgPixels.data[i + 1] = avg;
          imgPixels.data[i + 2] = avg;
        }
    }

    canvasContext.putImageData(imgPixels, 0, 0, 0, 0, imgPixels.width, imgPixels.height);

    dataurl = canvas.toDataURL();
    var newimg = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + dataurl;
    return newimg;
}
```

But for some reason it doesn't work. It just doesn't display the grayscale image. I got the for loop code online and tweaked it.

Comment: Tweaked it how? What did it do originally (and did that work)?

Comment: What exactly "doesn't work"? Did you do some debugging? Where is the unexpected behaviour?

Comment: Uh, [`toDataURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL) already returns a full data URL, you don't need to prefix it (and it won't be a jpeg anyway)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several reasons this does not work. It would be a good thing for you to start checking console output to track bugs. Firefox "F12" for example, would tell you that `for(>var ...)` is a problem. ;)

Did you declare `canvas` somewhere, outside the code you shared with us? Is `dataurl` declared? The prefixing of `toDataUrl` is not needed...

Here's a basic html file I typed around your for-loop, that does turn "test.png" to grey. Maybe you want to save it somewhere, put a png into the same folder, and start editing stuff step by step, instead of copying code. If you feel up for a challenge try making it pass http://jslint.com/! (You'd have to replace the for loop with while loops, I guess). :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Canvas/ImgData Test</title>
</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="output"></canvas>
    <script>
        var cnv = document.getElementById('output');
        var cnx = cnv.getContext('2d');

        function grey(input) {
            cnx.drawImage(myimage, 0 , 0);
            var width = input.width;
            var height = input.height;
            var imgPixels = cnx.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);

            for(var y = 0; y < height; y++){
                for(var x = 0; x < width; x++){
                    var i = (y * 4) * width + x * 4;
                    var avg = (imgPixels.data[i] + imgPixels.data[i + 1] + imgPixels.data[i + 2]) / 3;
                    imgPixels.data[i] = avg;
                    imgPixels.data[i + 1] = avg;
                    imgPixels.data[i + 2] = avg;
                }
            }

            cnx.putImageData(imgPixels, 0, 0, 0, 0, imgPixels.width, imgPixels.height);
        }

        var myimage = new Image();
        myimage.onload = function() {
            grey(myimage);
        }
        myimage.src = "test.png";
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

i know you are looking for **converting dataURI to grayscale but**, if you want to convert the video feedback itself to grayscale or convert any image to grayscale you can use this code.

```css
.gray {
  filter: grayscale();
}
```

```html
 <!--hey use this style to show in gray scale. can even use to convert image to grayscale-->
 <video id="camera-stream" class="gray" ></video>
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't take the average of the 3 colour components, as they vary greatly in brightness (100% green is a lot brighter than 100% blue). The TV systems (PAL and NTSC) define the brightness of the greyscale picture as 29.9% Red + 58.7% Green + 11.4% Blue.