# Using sliders to make an image greyscale JS/HTML/CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to use sliders to make an image grey using only pure JavaScript, HTML and CSS.

The user uploads a file which is then put onto a canvas. Then I would like the user to be able to move the slider on the range input and depending on the value of the range, it will change how close to black and white the image becomes.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```js
let imageLoader = document.getElementById('imgFile');
imageLoader.addEventListener('change', handleImage, false);
let canvas = document.getElementById('imgCanvas');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');


function handleImage(e) {
  let reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(event) {
    let img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
      canvas.width = img.width;
      canvas.height = img.height;
      ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    }
    img.src = event.target.result;
  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
}
```

```html
<label for="img">Select image:</label>
<input type="file" id="imgFile" name="imgFile" accept="image/*">

<canvas id="imgCanvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
<label for="greyPic">Edit the greyscale: </label>
<input id="greyPic" type="range" min="10" max="100" value="100">
```

Comment: Where is the code that does greyscale?

Comment: That is what Im unsure of

Comment: Can you also define what exactly a *slider* is in your case?

Comment: Sorry, the slider is the range input type

Comment: Seems like you should search how to make image grayscale with canvas.

Comment: Do you want to just display the img getting grayer or do you definitely want to have it on a canvas?

Comment: If you want to put the img on a canvas and change that (as opposed to just using a CSS filter), look up converting rgb to hsl as to gray out a color partially you will want to diminish its saturation, not just take average or something of the r, g and b. Also this [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37174616/js-how-to-turn-image-object-into-grayscale-and-display-it can give you some pointers although the accepted answer has poor averaging rather than going via HSL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var slider = document.getElementById("greyPic");
var pic = document.getElementById("imgCanvas");

// Update the current slider value (each time you drag the slider handle)
slider.oninput = function() {
    var value = this.value;
    //add grayscale based on the value of the slider 
    pic.style.filter= `grayscale(${value}%)`;
}
```